# ASP.NET 3 layers using SQL Server stored procedures to insert multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

What I have is this. I have 3 tables: Clients, Employers and Calls. While both Clients and Employers are normal tables. Call reference both tables by id. I have one stored procedure to insert into the 3 tables. But the problem comes now inside the web app.

This is my table Client

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Client]
(
    [idClient] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [identityClient] [int] NULL,
    [nameClient] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Client] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

This is my table Employee

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
(
    [idEmploy] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nameEmployee] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

And this is my table Call

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Call]
(
    [idCall] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [idClient] [int] NULL,
    [idEmployee] [int] NULL,
    [descriptionCall] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [answerCall] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Llamadas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

And here is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertcALL]
    @idClient int,
    @nameClient nvarchar(50),
    @idEmployee int,
    @nameEmployee nvarchar(50),
    @descriptionCall nvarchar(50),
    @answerCall nvarchar(50)        
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Client (nameClient) VALUES (@nameClient)
    SELECT @idClient = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Employee (nameEmployee) VALUES (@nameEmployee)
    SELECT @idEmployee = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Call (idClient, idEmployee, descriptionCall, answerCall)
    VALUES (@idClient, @idEmployee, @descriptionCall, @answerCall)
END
```

Now using ASP.NET with 3 layers I have a entity layer where I use the gets and sets for each table in this case I have `Entity_Client`, `Entity_Employee` and `Entity_Call`. I also have a data layer with `Data_Client`, `Data_Employee` and `Data_Call`.

But then my problem come here. How do I call the function to read the 3 entities and be used for the `data_Call`?

This is my function inside `data_Call` to use the stored procedure `insertCall`

```
Public Function insertCall(ByVal dts As Entity_Call) As Boolean
        Try
            connect()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("insertCall")
            cmd.Connection = cnn
                       
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descriptionCall", dts._descriptionCall)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answerCall", dts._answerCall)
            
            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return False
        Finally
            disconnect()
        End Try
    End Function
```

Yes you can see I'm missing `nameClient` and `nameEmployee` but the problem is they are part of another entity class and I cannot use dts for those two. I tried this idea but it didn't work.

```
Public Function insertCall(ByVal dts1 As Entity_Client, ByVal dts2 As Entity_Employee, ByVal dts3 As Entity_Call) As Boolean
        Try
            connect()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("insertCall")
            cmd.Connection = cnn
            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idClient", dts1._idClient)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameClient", dts1._nameClient)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idEmployee", dts2._idEmployee) 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameEmployee", dts2._nameEmployee) 
         
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descriptionCall", dts3._descriptionCall)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answerCall", dts3._answerCall)
            
            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return False
        Finally
            disconnect()
        End Try
    End Function
```

But obviously failed it always says it cannot find "@idClient". What I want to do is the user gets a screen where they insert the name of the client, the name of the employer who took care of the client, the description of the call and what answer was given. All this must be done on a click of one button. But no success and the error always pin point me in the `data_Call`.

How do I make a function to use the stored procedure of `insertCall` and call all the tables to use their Entity Class so it work?

Btw is not connectivity problem because I made two functions `insertClient` and `insertEmployee` and they work perfectly it just when the table needs the info of other tables.

At this point I feel is something easy but I cannot find a good solution. Please any help would be appreciate.

Comment: I didn't think someone would ask this. I just tag both because in the end is almost the same. Is not a problem related to c# or vb it just a small help of what is the right thing to do in this point.

Comment: It's an **employee** - not an "employe" .....

Comment: Ah yes my bad thanks for the edit!

Comment: Yeah I fixed the tags

Answer (score 0):

Change procedure like this

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertcALL]
    @idClient int = null,
    @nameClient nvarchar(50),
    @idEmployee int  = null,
    @nameEmployee nvarchar(50),
    @descriptionCall nvarchar(50),
    @answerCall nvarchar(50)        
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    if @idClient is null begin
    INSERT INTO Client (nameClient) VALUES (@nameClient)
    SELECT @idClient = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    end

    if @idEmployee is null begin
    INSERT INTO Employee (nameEmployee) VALUES (@nameEmployee)
    SELECT @idEmployee = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    end 

    INSERT INTO Call (idClient, idEmployee, descriptionCall, answerCall)
    VALUES (@idClient, @idEmployee, @descriptionCall, @answerCall)
END
```

Now You have set/null value for @idClient param.

When param is null - proc add new clientid and this new value addedto call

and so on